# Problem fitting a function containing a sum with scipy (curve_fit)

Tags: python, scipy, sum, curve-fitting, exponential

This is my first post, so please don't be too harsh
if the information are not perfect.

I am a average user of scipy and I commonly use it for fitting....
I have seen that similar questions have been asked but I really cannot get
my head around this problem....

This is the (simplify version) of the function I am trying to fit:

[function to fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTkWx.png)

(where the sum is for odd numbers up to n)

and my code:

```
def func(x, a, b, n_max):
    y = 0
    for n in np.arange(1, n_max ,2):
        y =+ 2*a + 4*np.pi * (1/(n*a))*math.exp(n*b*x) 
    return y


a = 10
n_max = 20
parameters, covariance = curve_fit(lambda x, b: func(x, a, b, n_max), 
                                   x_data, 
                                   y_data)
```

it gives me the error:
It give me the error "TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars".
I know what this error means but I cannot figure out how to correct my code.

Here I have two problems to tackle:

1. I need to fit a sum.... and despite a couple of examples on Stack, I cannot get how to take care of it. It would be amazing to get few line to explain it.
2. The parameters "a" and "n" should be fixed values which I am going to provide depending of the situation. So no optimisation should be done for them. (This should be addressed using lambda in the curve_fit.)

Any hint or example solution will be more than appreciated... cheers

Comment: Welcome to SO, your post looks good. If you want to improve the post quality you can read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Hi @blondelg, thank you... 
I will have a look at the link and I will tidy up the post....

Answer (score 1):

[`curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) will call your function with values that are NumPy arrays.  [`math.exp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.exp) doesn't know how to operate on a NumPy array and that leads to the error.  Instead of using `math.exp`, use [`np.exp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.exp.html).

Comment: I cannot believed I resolved all the previous bugs and got stuck on something like this. Thanks @Warren Weckesser , the advice resolved the problem.....